# How to approach converting to and from kafka messages?

Tags: design, compiler, data, apache-kafka

I would like to have a series of small stand-alone services that would either consume a Kafka topic and output the data into a different system or the reverse: receive data from a system and produce Kafka messages. What would be the right approach for such applications?

#### Example 1: Converting a SQL query result into a stream of Kafka messages

Let's take for example the case DB -> Kafka. Ideally the service would be configured with an Avro schema and a SQL query along with the connection configuration (URL, credentials, topic, consumer group etc.)

`schema.avsc`:

```
{
   "type" : "record",
   "namespace" : "BookExample",
   "name" : "book",
   "fields" : [
      { "name" : "title" , "type" : "string" },
      { "name" : "year" , "type" : "int" }
   ]
}
```

`query.sql`:

```
SELECT title, year from books;
```

And once started, the application would execute the query and pipe the results into Kafka.

Now, since both the input and output are configurations the system cannot be type checked at compile time. It would have to throw some form of error (parsing error?) at runtime once it tries to run.

Note also, that the application is underdefined. For simplicity it would map directly columns to fields of the same name (since order is not guaranteed for an Avro schema). That is fine. Maybe a more complex application could take a map `{columnName:fieldName}` but that is not important for this example.

#### Example 2: Persisting Kafka messages into a DB table

The same as Example 1 but in reverse. Now the SQL query is not even needed. Only a table name as configuration is needed (assuming the `column-field` convention as before).

The application would consume a Kafka topic with the Avro schema above and write each message as a row in the target table.

#### Example 3: HTTP

The same could be done for a web service that receives a JSON payload and publishes it to the configured Kafka topic. A 400 status code can be sent in case the payload does not conform to the Avro schema.

#### What have I done?

We did implement small applications as above in Scala. But the problem is we could not make them fully generic. Both the Avro schema and the table definition are needed at compile time to create the objects. That makes the application pretty inflexible.

#### What should I do?

My first thought was to implement it in a untyped or dynamic typed language (Python?). But that started to look a lot like parsing text input and generating code (in case of SQL). That is why I wrote this question. I'm not sure this is the right approach. It looks to me that this application is a kind of compiler/interpreter but applied to data instead of code? Transforming one type of data (text?) into another. **I need some pointers to other tools or literature that deals with this kind of data conversion problem.**

#### Available tools

I know about [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/index.html) (though I never used it) and it seems to me it is something very tightly coupled to the Kafka broker. I was wondering if there could be a lightweight application, easily deployed and transparent to the Kafka broker. For the broker the application would look like a normal consumer or producer.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77288836/how-to-approach-the-conversion-of-kafka-messages-from-and-to-other-systems

Answer (score 4):

this sounds like a standard ETL (Extract Transform Load) task, in that you are ,as you say,:

> started to look a lot like parsing text input and generating code

Various out of the box tools exist, where you essentially use a config syntax to define the transform. Are you trying to write a competing tool with a better config syntax? Or do you have a single case that means it isn't worth getting one of the generic tools?

In either case writing your own generic system from scratch seems like a large project with dubious benefits. I would simply hardcode microservices as needed for my specific connections